# Ассемблерные вставки. Проблема с mov

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, intel

```
 x:=StrToInt(Edit1.Caption);
 y:=StrToInt(Edit2.Caption);
 z:=StrToInt(Edit3.Caption);
{$asmmode intel}
 asm
xor edx,edx
mov eax,y
mov ecx,z
div ecx
mov Test,eax
mov eax,x
mov ecx,Test
div ecx
mov Test,eax
end;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Test));
```

Есть такой код, Остановка программы на "div ecx". Как я понял проблема в 
"mov Test,eax"
Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Переменные x,y,z,Test Integer

Comment: А y или z не равны 0 случайно?

Comment: @BigTows Помимо отсутствия проверок деления на ноль, вы, похоже, забыли обнулить `edx` перед второй операцией деления. Советую для начала написать код на паскале, а потом посмотреть как он будет трансформирован в ассемблер самой Delphi (View - Debug Windows - CPU Windows - Disassembly).

Answer (score 2):

1. В Delphi нету директивы `$ASMMODE`, она есть в Lazarus. Соответственно, ваш код, который вы приводите в качестве примера, просто не компилируется.
2. Имя переменной `Test` выбрано неудачно, поскольку оно совпадает с ассемблерной командой. Лучше переименовать, но причина ошибки не в этом.
3. У меня ваш код при некоторых входных параметрах работает нормально, а при некоторых вываливается сообщение: `integer divide by zero at XXXX` как раз на предпоследней инструкции ассемблерной вставки `div ecx`. Под отладчиком видно, что в `ecx` действительно `0`. Тестовые данные, при которых возникает ошибка: `x := 1; y := 2; z := 3`. Чтобы исключить ошибку деления на ноль, вам нужно переписать свой алгоритм. А с командой `mov` никаких проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить имя переменной `Test`, так как `test` - [встроенная команда ассемблера](http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/test/).